# How to synchronize project over FTP with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ftp, remote-server, synchronize

I am currently using SVN to get last development and production versions for my PHP websites projects on my remote server.
I use tags to create new versions, this is working fine and doing what i want.
But now, I want to automatically synchronize changes from my local projects to a remote folder on this server through FTP/SFTP to create a live development version.
It appears that Eclipse does not come with a native solution to do that, in fact i didn't find any appropriate solution.

I need to keep SVN as the Team provider of my projects and synchronize the entire projects or even the workspace with the remote folder.
Do you know any way to do that ?

I tried RSE and Aptana but it does not seem to do what i want.
On one of my PC, i am using Seafile with another server, this is working fine but this is not the purpose of this application, it's not embedded in Eclipse and it's very long to synchronize minor changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sftp access you can mount the remote directory locally (at least on linux). Then you can use `cp` and `rsync`.

Comment: This is a good solution but harder to get under windows and not in Eclipse context...

Comment: There are solutions to mount sftp on window, too.

Comment: Yes i did. But I think i will have some trouble with big files (in MB), due to the remote access and the usage of SVN...
SVN commit locally and the files are on a remote server, so the files will be uploaded to the remote FTP, then downloaded to commit them to the SVN (uploaded again)... It seems i will be wasting some times.